# Not enough Resources - Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have received this error after years of having this instance `Operation type [start] failed with message "The zone 'projects/instance-284213/zones/europe-west2-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."`

I have contact GCP support and was pointed to https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones. However, after following the guidelines and attached the disk to the new instance - I am unable to access the instance through gcloud or ssh. The instance is running, all firewall rules are intact and ssh is running but the websites on that instance is not showing or displaying. This instance was running since 2019 and only started giving me the above error three days ago. When I tried to access the instance through gcloud shell, I am receiving error: `ssh: connect to host "instance IP here" port 22: Connection timed out ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].` I have exhausted all options and I don't want to lose the data on that disk.

Comment: I appreciate that you commented and trying to help. Stack Overflow exist for this reason. If I could find the answers then I would not post this question. I have been using Stack Overflow for years and have not post a single question because I've found in the past what I am looking for. The good thing about this environment is that most people have the knowledge and understanding of how things work and some don't. So therefore each one help one to achieve a common purpose and not letting others feel inferior for posting a question one doesn't understand

Comment: All the answers you have suggested didn't work and I have not found any solutions to this issue I am facing. This VM holds my business websites. The vm crashes when it starts complaining that zone doesn't have enough resources. I followed GCP guidelines in moving VM between zones and created a new instance, attached the disk. I can't ssh into the VM, the serial console errors only showing what is inside the disk but not allowing me to access those files. The internal IP that I post is an old internal ip the troubled vm was using even though it has now changed when I create a new instance